# Is it possible to test static private methods used from public static methods with Mockito (not PowerMockito!)?

Tags: java, static, mockito, inline, private

I have a public static method which internally uses another static but private method. SonarQube bothers me to test this private method. How can I do this using Mockito (inline)?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static boolean isXxxValid(String value1, String value2) {
        try {
            var s = myPrivateMethod(anyString);
            ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
        }
    }

    private static String myPrivateMethod(final String input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I test or mock `myPrivateMethod()`?

Comment: You should test the public static method and in doing so you can test the functionality of the private method.

Answer (score 0):

In general the testing of private methods should be done via the business interface (the public methods of your class).

But since you are mentioning powermock I guess your idea is to mock that privat method to test your public method. That would be another anti pattern. You should never mock parts of the class under test.

In your case it seem that you need to mock the external dependencies that are used in your private method.

Comment: In the private method there are only some if-statements which SonarQube wants to be covered by tests. I could make this method public but since it is used only internally/in this class I suppose that SonarQube would complain to make this method private.

Comment: What hinders you to set up tests via the public method so that all branches of the if statements are covered?

Comment: LOL ... that's what I finished right now.